# netbeans problem : localhost/­PhpProject1/­index.­php not found

Tags: php, netbeans, windows-7

I have installed netbeans6.9.1 with java,c++ and php on windows 7. When i tried to run a test php code, the browser cant find the localhost. 
Pleas help me to get rid of this issue. do i need to install anything else? or to configure anything?

Comment: Think you might need an apache server running on your machine. Can you open http://127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Netbeans creates its own localhost at port 8383. Installing apache is something different. Question is just; for me too netbeas localhost:8383 is not working which used to work till few days ago. Can anyone explain how to fix

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Apache,PHP on your machine . Easiest way to do so is to download : [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)